# How do i convert my existing REST Api to a GraphQL API

Tags: api, rest, graphql

I'm new to GraphQL and I'm trying to covert one of my existing REST Api to GraphQL API

Here are the operations available today for REST API
1. POST - Creates Single/Multiple documents(Bulk Operation)Responds with Http 204
2. GET - Fetches a single document Responds with single doc Http 200 
3. PUT - Updates Single/Multiple documents (Bulk Operation) responds with Http 204

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL has two types of requests, queries (which get stuff), and mutations (which change stuff).

For a simple GraphQL starter I can recommend Apollo Server. It has one of the best documentations I have ever seen and provides you with a sandbox where you can test your requests.

The next step is to define a GraphQL schema, types and resolvers.

A relevant schema might be something along the lines of

```
type Document {
    id: String
    ...
}

type Query {
    documentById(id: String!): Document
}

type Mutation {
    createDocument(document: Document!): Document!
    createDocuments(documents: [Document!]): [Document!]
    updateDocument(document: Document!): Document!
    updateDocuments(documents: Document!): [Document!]
}

schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
}
```

Resolvers are handlers for your requests and these can be highly specific, but should be very similar to what you already implemented in REST.

Also, keep in mind gql will not use HTTP statuses to denote errors, all requests will result in a 200, even if they fail. Gql provides you with a error object in the result if something fails, so error handling on the consumers of your API have to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, here's where I get confused, for a mutation when trying to create/update multiple documents what is returned/what can be returned ex: mutation{
    Users(userInput:{

  }),{_id}
}

Comment: Also for Query we allow certain fields that are user defined a key value pair which is not predefined so how can a Query be written on Server for those feilds

Comment: If I understood your question, a mutation can return basically anything you want, although it is a good practice to return what was changed by the operation.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the second question you asked please? I would use a JSON string for a general key-value storage. All fields in gql are strongly typed and predefined as far as I know, a `generalStorage: String` could work for your use case.